# Scalable approach to make values in a list as column values in a dataframe in pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scalable

I have a pandas dataframe which has only one column, the value of each cell in the column is a list/array of numbers, this list is of length 100 and this length is consistent across all the cell values.

We need to convert each list value as a column value, in other words have a dataframe which has 100 columns and each column value is at a list/array item.

Something like this
[image]

becomes [image]

It can be done with iterrows() as shown below, but we have around 1.5 million rows and need a scalable solution as iterrows() would take alot of time.

```
cols = [f'col_{i}' for i in range(0, 4)]
df_inter = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df_inter.loc[len(df_inter)] = row['message']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'message':[[1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6,7]]})

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
           message
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [30]: res = pd.DataFrame(df.message.tolist(), index= df.index)

In [31]: res
Out[31]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  3  4  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

`df.message.apply(pd.Series)`

To use dask to scale (assuming it is installed):

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)
ddf.message.apply(pd.Series, meta={0: 'object'})
```

Comment: This is quite slow when it comes to large data frames.

Comment: In that case you might consider using something like dask to help scale.

Comment: `df.apply(pd.Series)` is really slow. My solution performs better than that. You don't need Dask just to do this.

Comment: No need for a big data library......just avoid using `.apply`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) is more about problems with `.apply` that should be considered before using it.